# Compute a tight upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^i\log{n}- 3i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms

I am trying to compute a tight upper bound of the sum below.

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n\frac{\frac{1}{3^i}}{\log_3{(n/3^i)}}$

I was able to 'simplify' it up to the expression below.

$n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^i(\log_3{n}- i)}$.

Comment: Why do you assume such a closed form exists?

Comment: I did not mean that. I only need to get a tight upper bound of the expression.

Comment: The terms start to become negative as soon as $i>\log_3(n)$. So an upper bound is given by the shorter sum where the upper limit $n-1$ is replaced by $\log_3(n)$.